# How do you specify PHP version for Composer so that it won't download the latest builds?

Tags: composer-php, restler, illuminate-container

I have shared hosting with PHP 5.3.8 where I cannot run Composer.

Yesterday I have installed Composer to my own computer and then I have "build" [Restler](https://github.com/Luracast/Restler) with it. It has downloaded [Illuminate](https://github.com/illuminate/database) too. Then I've uploaded them to my shared hosting and it didn't work because apparently Illuminate requires minimum PHP 5.4.

So, is there any possibility to specify PHP version for Composer? Or I should have switched PHP 5.6 off, and then PHP 5.3.x on on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using Restler 3 RC5, RC6 already have those dependencies removed

Restler uses illuminate only when you use blade templates, so you can saf. You can run composer update with no dev option

```
composer update --no-dev
```

For more details see https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update

This will install only the packages needed for production environment. Then you can upload the files to server and all should be fine.